# Color package interferes with sections

Tags: sectioning, color

I would like to use the `color` package to define custom color for listings background but when I include it it creates nasty side effect on my numbered section headers (only section, not lower levels). This is how the section header looks like:

- color package is included
  [image: When color package is included]
- color package is commented
  [Color package commented]
  [image]

I think the problem is with this package because this happens only when I include it.

This is my preamble file:

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  %postavljanje margine
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{croatian}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[hang,small,bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{tocloft}  %tablica sadržaja
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}  %točkice na sadržaju
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{setspace}  %postavi prored
\onehalfspacing  %prored 1.5
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\input{glossary}
\renewcommand{\acronymname}{Oznake i kratice}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{parskip}  %preskakanje paragrafa

%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}  %postavke za pseudokodiranje i umetanje koda
\lstset{
  language=C,                % choose the language of the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers.        
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  %backgroundcolor=\color{gray},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
}

%naslovi
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\scshape\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{secdot}
\sectiondot{subsection}
\sectiondot{subsubsection}

%brojevi uz podnaslove
\usepackage{chngcntr,tocloft}
\counterwithin*{figure}{section}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsection}
\counterwithin*{figure}{subsubsection}

\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{2em}


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}=0
    \thesection.\arabic{figure}%
  \else
    \ifnum\value{subsubsection}=0
      \thesubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \else
      \thesubsubsection.\arabic{figure}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `xcolor` ?

Comment: Please make your example into a complete document starting `\documentclass` and including a section heading, to show the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that `color` is not compatible with the "easy interface" of `titlesec`; here's how you can do instead.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalsize\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection. }
  {0pt}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalsize}
  {\thesubsubsection. }
  {0pt}
  {}
```

Don't load the `secdot` package and remove the relative calls, because dots can be easily added with `titlesec` itself.

---

Some other points. Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` that's necessary for typesetting in languages with diacritics. Move the call to `hyperref` as the last package loaded.

The `\scshape\bfseries` declaration for `\section` is useless, because of your `\MakeUppercase`, so `\bfseries` is sufficient.

Comment: Excellent @egreg! Thank you for the rest of your advices.

Comment: I think I'll be in Croatia, tomorrow (Poreč); maybe you can buy me a coffee. `;-)`